# Finding geolocation from image

Tags: android, jpeg, gps

I use the app Open Camera on my Android phone. I have enabled "Store location data (Geotagging) / store GPS location data in photos". I have transfered some photos to my computer and would like to know the location they were taken at. How can this be done? I checked the preferences and didn't see anything special in them. I have photoshop if that's a help. My comp is running Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Windows File Explorer and navigate to the location of your image
2. Right click the image and choose Properties
3. Click the Details tab at the top of the window
4. Now scroll down towards the bottom and you'll see a GPS section with the latitude and longitude that your photo was geotagged with
5. Now look up those coordinates on Google Maps or wherever else you prefer

Comment: Thanks! By chance do you know how to copy the values or do you need to write them down manually?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to do it manually, unless someone knows of a trick that I'm unaware of