# Windows Explorer - Details view - column for geolocation - Latitude and Longitude

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-filter

Windows [can read these metadata](https://superuser.com/a/1145251/207006) but omits them from the choice of columns:

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sub>(note the blank Location column in the background of this screenshot)</sub>

Am I missing it, or must it be hacked?

At least, how might I query and sort my files on this attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Your first screenshot has a 'Location' option.

Comment: And my third screenshot shows it selected (it is subtle - updated my post), but being blank in Windows Explorer even for the selected file which has GPS data.

Answer (score 4):

I knew I'd ansewred this somewhere before!
[enter link description here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/accessing-file-properties-latitude-and-longitude/4b93bfc1-9970-439c-8f21-0f4554a5ab0d)

Here is updated code that adds **Latitude**, **Longitude**, and **Altitude** as available columns for folders using the **Pictures** template. Copy & paste into a **PowerShell** window:

---

### Edit 2023/08/23: Code now modifies PIctures, PIcturews.SearchREsults, and PIctures.Library FolderTypes

---

```
$HKLM_FT  = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
$HKCU_FT  = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
$PictruesTV              = "{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
$PicturesSearchResultsTV = "{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}\TopViews\{5586158e-f4e6-409e-b47c-4d216f40b912}"
$PicturesLibraryTV       = "{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5}\TopViews\{82ba0782-5b7a-4569-b5d7-ec83085f08cc}"

$CustomTVs = @($PictruesTV, $PicturesSearchResultsTV, $PicturesLibraryTV)

###   Copy specified FolderTypes from HKLM to HKCU
$CustomTVs | %{
    New-Item -Path (Join-Path $HKCU_FT $_) -Force | Out-Null
    $SPlat = @{
       'Path'        = Join-Path $HKLM_FT $_
       'Destination' = Join-Path $HKCU_FT (Split-Path $_)
    }
    Copy-Item @Splat -force
}

###   Modify ColumnList in newly-creaeted HKCU entries
$Find    = '(?<=0[A-Za-z\.]+\;)1' 
$Replace = '1System.GPS.Latitude;1System.GPS.Longitude;1System.GPS.Altitude;1'

$CustomTVs | %{
    $SPlat = @{
       'Path' = Join-Path $HKCU_FT $_
       'Name' = 'ColumnList'
    }
    $ColumnList = (Get-ItemPropertyValue @Splat) -replace $Find, $Replace
    Set-ItemProperty @Splat -Value $ColumnList

get-process explorer | stop-process
```

[image]
[image]

Update: For those that prefer a .reg file option...

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}]
"ColumnList"="prop:0System.ItemNameDisplay;0System.ItemDate;0System.ItemTypeText;0System.Size;0System.Keywords;1System.GPS.Latitude;1System.GPS.Longitude;1System.GPS.Altitude;1System.DateCreated;1System.DateModified;1System.Photo.DateTaken;1System.Image.Dimensions;1System.Rating"
"IconSize"=dword:00000060
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
"Name"="NoName"
"Order"=dword:00000000
```